# How to put an image over the content of a div?

Tags: html, css, meteor

I want to display my locker image at the right of the `div` but kept the `div` size and format.

that's the default state:
[image]

that's what happens now when I lock:
[image]

And I want to do something like this:

[image]

To make this I made this css:

```
.imgCadenas{
  width:  100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url('/cadenas.png');
  text-align: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

and the HTML is not special but I put it:

```
<template name="machine">
    <li class="liMachine switch">
        <div id="nameMachine">
            <h3>{{nameMachine}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="stateMachine">
            State:<span class="state">{{stateMachine}}</span>
        </div>
        {{#if isLocked}}
        <div>
          <img class="imgCadenas">
        </div>
        {{else}}
          {{#if hideStopM}}
            {{else}}
              {{#if is_running_machine}}<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
            {{else}}<button type="button" class="stop {{#if to_hide_stopM}}hidden{{/if}}"></button>
            {{/if}}
          {{/if}}

          {{#if hideKillM}}
          {{else}}
            {{#if is_alive_machine}}<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
              {{else}}<button type="button" class="kill {{#if to_hide_stopM}}hidden{{/if}}"></button>
            {{/if}}
          {{/if}}

          {{#if is_stopped_machine}}<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>{{else}}<button type="button" class="start {{#if to_hide_startM}}hidden{{/if}}"></button>{{/if}}
        {{/if}}
    </li>
</template>
```

*the part I'm working on is the `{{#if isLocked}}`*

When I use `float:right` I have :
[image]

When I use the solution of setting the `position: absolute;top:0px..`:
[image]

When I use the solution of @this.believer:
[image]

Comment: I don't understand. You mean,you want the locker image to come to the right side of the div?

Comment: @this.Believer yes and to keep the `div` size

Comment: have a look at my solution it  will work for all the div sizes and image sizes. @Jerome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would edit the position of the div as follows and make sure the parent div has also a set position e.g. position:relative;

```
.imgCadenas{          
   position: absolute;
   top: 4px;
   right: 4px;
 }
```

Comment: Yes I think I'll need to do that because it's the only one who works as I wish

Comment: Do keep in mind that if your div has many siblings you should also set a higher z-index so that it appears infront of them.

Comment: Btw it's not a good solution because it's not reactive, I should hard-code for each div

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean reactive but if you mean responsive then the "absolute" position of the img is absolute in regards to the parent element. If the parent element is relative and has e.g. width: 100% then your image will move accordingly as well.

Comment: Yes what I wanted to say is: if I display this image one a 2nd "machine" (the html that you can see) the image will be at the same place as the first image etc... If you don't understand ask me I can do a picture

Comment: Well not really. As I mentioned before the absolute position is absolute to the DOM only if the parent doesn't have a set position. So if your structure looks like the following then each image will align inside your "machine".

`<div class='machine' style='position:relative;'><div class='imgCadenas'></div></div>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139332/discussion-between-jerome-and-stavros-angelis).

Answer (score 1):

Define position if li as relative

```
.liMachine{
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;  
}
```

and for image

```
.imgCadenas{
  width:  100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url('/cadenas.png');
  text-align: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
/* Add following css */
position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
}
```

Comment: @TehPatil look the edit, it's a bit strange but better than before

Comment: You might not have added  position:relative;  for its parent. When parent is relative the child reacts with parents position else it is positioned with body

Answer (score 1):

using float and keeping the postion relative on the image would fix the issue.

```css
img {
  postion: relative;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li id="hello">
      <a href="home.php"><img src="http://zdnet3.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/2015/09/01/cb834e24-18e7-4f0a-a9bf-4c2917187d3f/83bb139aac01023dbf3e55a3d1789ad8/google-new-logo.png"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: it makes the same thing as the last picture in my question BUT the image is at the bottom of the `div` and in the post it's at the top of the `div`...

Comment: try using `line-height:0%` and tell me the result.

Comment: the lock image should be inside the green div?

Comment: Yes as in the "paint" image that I made to show the expected result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139329/discussion-between-jerome-and-this-believer).

Answer (score 0):

add the following to .imgCadenas class

```
float: right;
```

Comment: it makes something bad look the edit (I'm not the downvoter)

Answer (score 0):

add this to your CSS classes :

```
.imgCadenas{
  z-index:5;
  position: absolute;
  right:/*some px/vw from the right side*/;
  top:/*some spx/vh from the top*/;
  bottom:/*same as above if vertically centered*/;
  left:auto;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
}

.liMachine{
  position: relative;
}
```